# why I am getting the following when there is no problem with spaces?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to run the following code. I checked 4 tabs after for but still I am getting error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block` .

```
    # writing vectors(inverse indexing) of top_k_terms in ranks.txt
f = open("ranks.txt",'w')                                       
for i in range(len(top_k_terms)):
    pickle.dump((newInverseIndexingDict[top_k_terms[i]]),f)
f.close()
```

if you need to know what is `newInverseIndexingDict[top_k_terms[i]]`, for `i=0` it is

`[0.0, 0.7959605415681652, 0.0]`

and so on.

Comment: This is not reproducible on the code shown. The problem is caused by this code failing to line up with **previous code that is not shown**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Python even checks the indentation of comments, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, that’s *fortunately.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can indent comments just how you want. The problem here comes from having the **first line** of the script indented. Strange things happen if you later have a block that starts at the same indent level as this first line, or it you cross this indent level between two more deeply indented blocks.

Comment: @elham Note that this answer, that you accepted, is just plain wrong, as explained in my previous comment.